# Make movieclip visible true or false with xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Trying to make a movieclip visible or not through XML. This is the line of code I am using and it throws up a whole page of errors.

```
item1_mc.visible =  myXML.children()[0].children()[0];
```

What is the proper syntax ?

Comment: We have no idea unless  you show us the XML.

Comment: May be you mean : `item1_mc.visible = myXML.children()[0].children()[0] == "true";` ? Show us your xml and the errors that you'v got that will be more easy to know the origin of the problem !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there is a trap when converting Strings to Booleans in AS3.

```
v = Boolean(0); // false
v = Boolean(1); // true
v = Boolean(123); // true

v = Boolean(""); // false
v = Boolean(null); // false
v = Boolean(undefined); // false
v = Boolean("test"); // true
v = Boolean("true"); // true
v = Boolean("false"); // true !!!
```

ex) If your XML includes this element and you want to use it.

```
<isLogin>false</isLogin>
```

AS3 regards that false value as String, doesn't regard as Boolean type.

```
item1_mc.visible = "false";
```

equals

```
item1_mc.visible = true;
```

So, this might not be a cool solution, however I think you should compare the XML value with string value of "true/false" and set the boolean value of true/false.

```
if (myXML.children()[0].children()[0] == "true"){
    item1_mc.visible = true;
}
else{
    item1_mc.visible = false;
}
```

Or following code also works.

```
item1_mc.visible = myXML.children()[0].children()[0] == "true";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. While we are on the subject, how would one use xml to tell a movieClip to gotoAndStop on a frame?

Comment: @rastovich Please show us some code and xml.
But actually I don't know much at flash. I usually work with flex, haven't work with flash...